# Comparação PHP não funciona

Tags: php

Galera estou com um problema, a comparação não esta funcionando, Ele deveria retornar a mensagem de "Tudo certo" mas acaba retornando apenas a mensagem de "Validos apenas números de 1 a 60"

```
    <?php 

    $a = array(1,2,3,4,60);
    $b = count($a);
    $u = count(array_unique($a));

    echo "Original: ".$b."<br>"."Unicos: ".$u."<br>";
    if($b === $u){
        foreach($a as $aceitos){
            if($aceitos > 0 AND $aceitos < 61) {
                echo "Validos apenas números de 1 a 60";
            }else{
                echo "Tudo certo";
            }
        }
        echo "Arrays iguais";
    }else{
        echo "Arrays diferentes";
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você só errou ali na condição

```
    if($aceitos > 0 AND $aceitos < 61) {
            echo "Validos apenas números de 1 a 60";
        }
```

Nessa condição, seriam os números que seriam aceitos, no caso entre 0 e 60, mas a mensagem que você esta ao contrario, porque se entrou nessa condição, o numero esta correto. Ou você inverte o if com o else, ou você faz dessa forma:

```
    $a = array(1,2,3,4,60);
    $b = count($a);
    $u = count(array_unique($a));

    echo "Original: ".$b."<br>"."Unicos: ".$u."<br>";
    if($b === $u){
        foreach($a as $aceitos){
            echo $aceitos;
            if($aceitos < 0 || $aceitos > 60) {
                echo "Validos apenas números de 1 a 60<br>";
            }else{
                echo "Tudo certo";
            }
        }
        echo "Arrays iguais";
    }else{
        echo "Arrays diferentes";
    }

 ?>
```

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Você confundiu na na condicional.

`if($aceitos > 0 AND $aceitos < 61)`

deveria ser

`if($aceitos < 1 OR $aceitos > 60)`

Comment: Me confundi mesmo, mas foi porque já fiz varias alterações e nada funciona, agora por exemplo, mesmo eu arrumando a comparação se eu colocar "0" no array ele não identifica como erro, ele exibe a mensagem de "tudo certo" e se eu coloco um valor "60" no array ele funciona direito, o meu problema agora é sobre o "0"

Comment: então é preciso usar `$aceitos < 1` que ele vai identificar o zero como erro.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Não tem como ser menor que 1 E maior que 60 ao mesmo tempo, o correto é usar menor que 1 OU maior que 60

Comment: Bem colocado @JaderA.Wagner, nem tinha percebido. Atualizado.